# Aggregating Data with Multiple Rows in a Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to take the table below and aggregate start and end time information into a single master table. For simplicity, I am just concentrating on aggregating the Discover Start and End times (Start time is StartedOn where DispatchType = Data.Matter;Import and End time is FinishedOn here DispatchType = Data.Matter;DataExtract).

The common ID between the two dispatchtypes is the settingsid.

Mock up of Jobs:

[jobstable names #Jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHgcn.png)

Mock up of collection table I am trying to aggregate to:

[collection table named #JobsTableCollection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyKPZ.png)

A simple update join like below does not work:

```
UPDATE jtc
SET jtc.JobsTable_DiscoveryStartTime = (SELECT jobs.StartedOn = CASE jobs.DispatchType WHEN 'Data.Matter;Import' THEN jobs.StartedOn END),
    jtc.JobsTable_DiscoveryEndTime = (SELECT jobs.FinishedOn WHERE jobs.DispatchType = 'Data.Matter;DataExtract'),
FROM #JobsTableCollection AS jtc
INNER JOIN #Jobs AS jobs ON jtc.DiscoveryGroupId = jobs.SettingsId
```

I am looking into creating an update via a CTE but was curious if anyone has some advice on a better way to try and aggregate this information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the following variant

```
UPDATE jtc
SET jtc.JobsTable_DiscoveryStartTime = ISNULL(jobs1.StartedOn,'19000101'),
    jtc.JobsTable_DiscoveryEndTime = ISNULL(jobs2.FinishedOn,'19000101')
FROM #JobsTableCollection AS jtc
LEFT JOIN #Jobs AS jobs1 ON jtc.DiscoveryGroupId = jobs1.SettingsId AND jobs1.DispatchType = 'Data.Matter;Import'
LEFT JOIN #Jobs AS jobs2 ON jtc.DiscoveryGroupId = jobs2.SettingsId AND jobs2.DispatchType = 'Data.Matter;DataExtract'
```